# How to remove all duplicated words in a Word document

Tags: ms-word, office365

I regularly have word documents where words are repeated, for example: "they they ate their dinner." - I would like if possible to remove all duplicated words from my Word documents without having to go through Spell Check and individually remove repeated words.

I appreciate I can use find and replace, but with the transcribed spoken word the list of duplicate words is very long, as you can imagine.

Is there a quicker way to achieve this result?

I have Googled it of course, but all the results I have found are "have you tried find and replace?" - Ah. Yes. No thank you, lol.

Thanks in advance,
S

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a VBA macro in case if only the desktop edition of Word must be supported. See [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office).

Otherwise, consider creating a Word add-in, see [Build your first Word task pane add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think that's a bit advanced for me lol. I was hoping there was some options I could check somewhere haha. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove repeated words in a Word document efficiently, you can use a combination of Microsoft Word's built-in features and a simple macro. Here are the steps:

1. Open your Word document
2. Press Alt + F11 to open the Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) editor.
3. In the VBA editor, click on Insert in the menu, then choose Module. This will open a new module window.
4. Copy and paste the following VBA code into the module window:

---

```
Sub RemoveDuplicateWords()
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim word As Range

        Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range
    
        For Each word In rng.Words
            If word.Text = word.Next.Words(1).Text Then
                word.Next.Words(1).Delete
            End If
        Next word
    End Sub
```

---

5. Close the VBA editor by clicking the X button or pressing Alt + Q.
6. Now, you can run the macro. To do this, press Alt + F8, select RemoveDuplicateWords, and click Run.

This macro will iterate through each word in the document and delete any duplicate words that follow one another. It's a quicker way to remove repeated words compared to manually using Find and Replace, especially when dealing with a large number of occurrences.